# How to monitor my Wireless connection

Tags: network-monitoring

I have setup a Home Wifi zone and can connect my laptop/phone to it successfully.

I want to know, whether there is any tool/command which allows me to monitor my network connection easily. For example I want to make sure that it's me only who is connected to the network.

Comment: kismet comes to mind...not a simple command that just does it, but it can be used.

Comment: What router do you use? Several routers have the ability to send logs over mail. Also have a look at 'keyloggers' and 'snooping' .

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, not a simple one, but good to know that if we spend time to learn it, the tool can be useful.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for your suggestion. I have to check whether my router has that facility or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing Zenmap from the Ubuntu software centre. This tool allows you to scan your LAN (and therefore wifi) for other devices.

Zenmap would only be useful when you manually run it.  If you need a continuous background monitoring tool, I don't think it will help directly.  But the command-line nmap command could be scripted to keep an eye on your network periodically, and tell you if other IP addresses appear.

Comment: Many many Thanks Rick for your help. Now I have to learn about how to effectively use nmap. One help is here : http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/video/How-to-use-Nmap-to-scan-a-network. It will be more help for me, if you can please point me to any script that I can use. I am using a home Network. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

My dLink DIR-320 router has an admin page under Status&Log/WiFi menu entry which could be accessed via 192.168.1.1/Main_WStatus_Content.asp

It shows a list of MACs of connected to WiFi devices:

```
Mode    : AP Only
Channel : 1
Stations List                           
----------------------------------------
00:xx:cc:bb:aa:zz  associated
```

you can write a script which polls that url, parses returned html and sends you notifications on list changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see who's connected to your wireless network simply try this command

```
 arp -a -i wlan0
```

Where wlan0 is the network interface for the wireless card. It differs from PC to PC.