# How to get all mac addresses of the pcs connected to my wifi... from my wifi connected ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm looking to generate a list of the machines connected to my wifi.

**I'm myself connected though wifi, and would like to access this information though my wifi laptop** instead of the pc that has the router connected to it (as it runs on windows).

**I would like to use the shell to simply get a list of all the mac addresses connected.**

Is there a way to do that? I've read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40063/how-to-monitor-my-wireless-connection), and [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371879/how-to-manage-wifi-clients-in-ubuntu), and it seems that those solutions are for computers connected to the router using a cable, and not wireless themselves.

ie. if I do `arp -a -i wlan0`, I get my own laptop connected, but just my laptop.

Is there any way to do this? I've downloaded Kali repositories, so maybe there's some tool to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ie. if I do arp -a -i wlan0, I get my own laptop connected, but just my laptop.

Per the link you referenced

```
 sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet
```

So try that, or

```
 sudo arp -a -i wlan0 --localnet
```

And see if it returns more than just your laptop.

Comment: Just perfect, thanks! It work with sudo arp-scan --interface=wlan0 --localnet. Two last questions: Should I see the router in the list, and myself? Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure about the router, but I think you should see yourself. I'm at work on phone, otherwise I would try it. If your having an issue determining what what, maybe you need to run this first and then run the nmap scan sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24 and compare the two

Comment: sudo arp -n -i en1 -l -a this works on mac too. :)

Answer (score 1):

For computer/laptop connected to your AP you can do this:

1) Set your wifi card in monitor mode:

> sudo airmon-ng start wlan0

2) Then with airodump-ng you can view all wifi devices in your area, but you want to know only the devices connected to your AP so you have to filter the output:

> sudo airodump-ng --bssid 'AP's MAC address' mon0

For example: sudo airodump-ng --bssid FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF mon0 . 
In the lower part you will see how is connected.